# Firebase Real-Time Database size doubled

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

About 3 days Ago our Real-time Database Storage doubled really fast, we don't have much data since we just store user-s data and we do not have much users, but this made me think if someone found a way to write data on a way they should not or whatever.

Our database structure is:

```
/users/
  -/UID_1/profile
  -/UID_2/profile
```

I strongly believe that any of these guys wrote a bunch of something, but I am not able to know size on each "record" or how to call

Here, I should write on what did I try, but I didn't try anything yet, I am not sure on what to do, It's production db, and I am a bit afraid to touch it.

PS.
I have the backup file, it's about 25mb large when unzipped.

Looking forward to receive any suggestions,
Cheers

Comment: Have you examined your Firebase in the Firebase Console? That could be very revealing.

Comment: @Jay No I didn't, I don't have much experience with Firebase and I didn't find any right tool to do that. Could you help me out ?

Comment: Sure. Log into your Firebase account using a browser, then click Go To Console which should be in the upper right corner. Select your project and then on the left you can select Database which will then show you all the nodes in your database. For further assistance, reach out to Firebase support.

Comment: @Jay Well, that is not exactly what you said, I can see all the nodes in my database, but not any other info. But yeah, I will have to reach out to Firebase support. Thnx for your time I appreciate it